# NFS Datastore Appears Empty!

Tags: nfs, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I've got an NFS server problem.
The datastore connected and seems to be a valid datastore in both the vSphere client and under /vmfs/volumes.
The issue is that it appears to be empty!

I can create files (eg: touch /vmfs/volumes/nfs_common/thefile) and it is correctly written to the nfs store.
I can verify this by looking on the nfs server itself.
But the vmkernel only sees an empty datastore; the file disappears.

Another freebsd box can mount the same NFS share and see the files correctly.

Some useful data:
ESXi 4.0.0 Build 208167
NFS is unfsd running on a Buffalo Linkstation Pro Duo (a bit hacky I know).
The share has file system permissions set to 777 at the moment.

My /etc/exports is as follows, and as I say it connects fine.
/mnt/array1/ESX_Shared 192.168.16.0/255.255.255.0(insecure,rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

The ESXi servers can also successfully mount NFS shares from other NFS servers.

Any ideas guys?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Change the file encoding to BIG5.

I had the same problem with ANSI encoding. After changing it to BIG5 everything worked.

[image: where to change encoding to BIG5]

Don't forget to modify your `C:\WINDOWS\msnfs\\.maphost` file